# Windows time service configuration update by non-admin user

Tags: windows-10, services, privileges, user, non-admin

I want to configure Windows Time Settings as a non-administrator user and without using an elevated command prompt. I gave permission to user to change the system time from User Rights Assignments. 
Also I gave full control to user in registry for W32Time keys.

I can run commands such as:

- w32tm /query /peers
- w32tm /query /status
- w32tm /query /configuration
- w32tm /query /source
- w32tm /resync
- w32tm /config

without any problem but when I try to run:

- w32tm /config /update
- w32tm /unregister or /register

I encounter with Access Denied problem.

In order to run these commands as user, which permissions should I give to user?

Comment: Even as an Administrator, one has to elevate the permissions of the command prompt, before running the /update and /register commands.  However, just to make sure I understand what you have done.  Have you specifically given the user ownership over `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\w32time\Config`?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have added the user to the "Change the system time" policy ([link](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92910-allow-prevent-users-groups-change-time-windows-10-a.html)), and this should have worked.
Security rules on Windows do change rapidly and without notice.

You might try the classical trick of using the Task Scheduler for
[Elevated Program Shortcut without UAC Prompt](https://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/11949-elevated-program-shortcut-without-uac-prompt-create.html)
and let the user run the task using the command
[Schtasks /Run](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/schtasks#BKMK_run).
However, I'm unsure if this still works with the latest Windows 10.

If all fails, the Technet program
[Run As GUI](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Run-As-GUI-b23012b2#content)
might be another solution.
It keeps the entered Administrator password in a safe and encrypted format.